# How to have terminal repeat with different IP?

Tags: command-line, ip

Would it be possible to get terminal to repeat `nslookup` starting from `192.168.1.2` through `192.168.1.20` to look at all the computers in the network without having to go into the server. Is this possible?

Comment: You only have three bytes in the second IP. Please update with a proper IP.

Answer (score 2):

`nslookup` itself doesn't have support for CIDR notation, ranges or wildcards, so your best option is likely a simple bash loop.

```
for ip in 192.168.1.{2..20}; do nslookup $ip; done
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer of dfarrell07 solves the problem in a general way, not depending on `nslookup` - which is the right way to do it I think.

But for the sake of diversity, and shell syntax examples, here is another approach, more related to the domain name lookup:

The lookup program could be told to handle all addresses at once; That seems to be tricky with `nslookup`, (it may require using `expect`) so I will use `dig` instead.

There is an option `-x` for `dig` to do reverse lookups. That option takes only one address, so just listing them does not work. But there can be multiple queries on the command line, so the option can be repeated.

We can not use `192.168.1.{2..20}` for the list of addresses, because we need a `-x` in front of each one. Using `'-x 192.168.1.'{2..20}` places a `-x` in front of them - but not as a separate command line argument - `dig` would get `-x 192.168.1.2` as one argument, while it should see `-x` and `192.168.1.2`. I'll use a subshell expansion as a workaround to separate the words - but I'm sure there are more clean ways to do that.

**This command should list the host names you want:**

```
dig +noall +answer $(echo '-x 192.168.1'{2..20})
```

showing something like

```
$ dig +noall +answer $(echo '-x 193.99.144.'{80..83})  
80.144.99.193.in-addr.arpa. 20800 IN    PTR     redirector.heise.de.
81.144.99.193.in-addr.arpa. 20134 IN    PTR     www.ix-konferenz.de.
83.144.99.193.in-addr.arpa. 21599 IN    PTR     limesurvey.heise.de.
```

---

Regarding the separate command line arguments: you can try the following commands, they will show the same output, but in the first, the `echo` in front gets 11 arguments, each `-x` and IP address separate, while in the second, the `echo` only gets 7 arguments:

```
$ echo dig +noall +answer $(echo '-x 193.99.144.'{80..83})
dig +noall +answer -x 193.99.144.80 -x 193.99.144.81 -x 193.99.144.82 -x 193.99.144.83
$ echo dig +noall +answer '-x 193.99.144.'{80..83} 
dig +noall +answer -x 193.99.144.80 -x 193.99.144.81 -x 193.99.144.82 -x 193.99.144.83
```